# A question on Finite fields and irreducible polynomials.

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, information-theory

Why cannot a reducible polynomial (one that has factors besides 1 and itself) be used as the polynomial to generate a finite field?

That is to say, why do we always need an irreducible polynomial as a necessary condition to generate a finite field?

In other words, how do I prove that I cannot have a finite field if the polynomial used to construct the field is not an irreducible one?

Any detailed and logical explanation would be of much help.

Comment: I tried an example. Suppose, I have the field GF(2^3) and  I choose (x+1) (x^2 + x +1 ) as the polynomial to generate the field. This basically gives me, x^3 as the polynomial. So, basically, what is the problem here? I'm kind of new to this study, hence the doubt. @MorganRodgers

Comment: @Curiosity Can you evaluate the product $(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ in your ring?

Comment: The problem is that while $(x+1)$ and$(x^2+x+1)$ are not zero, their product is $0$.

Comment: Do you understand why $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by a polynomial generating a field. I can think of two different things that could mean, one of them needs irreducibility, one does not.

Comment: Well, the elements of the field are 0 and 1. So, (x+1) (x^2 + x + 1) = 0 as the polynomial would mean, x^3 = 0, which only gives the element 0, and no other element. Is that right?

Comment: I am talking of an extended field, like GF(2^3) formed from GF(2), using a polynomial to generate elements of the field.

Comment: "using a polynomial" - well how exactly? Which elements are "generated" in your example?

Comment: Well, I am, for an example, generating GF(2^3) from GF(2) using the polynomial x^3 + x +1 = 0.

Comment: You are not answering my question. How do you "use" it? What exactly do you do with it? And how and why does that polynomial generate that field in your opinion?

Comment: Well, all I know so far from my book is that a polynomial is needed to generate the elements of a field. I don't know greater details than that, hence the question. I don't have an opinion, as I'm just starting to learn.

Comment: Tell us a bit more about your background. A math student is **never** introduced to finite fields without giving them some background about polynomial rings, quotient rings, and when those may or may not be fields. I'm afraid some people from programming/telcomm programs are often dropped into, not quite the deep end, but not the shallowest section of the pool, by introducing finite fields without a thorough intro to other structures of abstract algebra. To give a helpful answer, we need such bits (possibly also something else).

Comment: I have this subject on error-control codes as a side course to my main course on machine learning. So, yeah, I agree that I do not know much detail about the prerequisites, mainly because of lack of exposure and time, at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

A field is in particular an integral domain. The ideal generated by a reducible polynomial is not a prime ideal, and therefore the quotient ring is not integral and thus cannot be a field.

Comment: Can you simplify the concept a little more? I'm new to this study, so a more detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your question @curiosity when you say “generate” a finite field are you talking about quotienting by my the ideal generated by the polynomial?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: What @user513723 is saying that if $I$ is the ideal generated by a reducible polynomial, say $p = f(x)g(x)$, then the ideal cannot be a prime ideal (are you familiar with prime ideals?) because $p$ is in I but $f,g$ are not. Anytime you quotient by and ideal that is not prime, the resulting ring is not an integral domain. In this case, $f$ and $g$ will be non-zero zero divisors. One of the requirements to be a field is to be an integral domain, so the resulting quotient object can not be a field

Comment: @Curiosity If you understand why $Z/kZ$ is a field iff $k$ is a prime number, you will understand the answer to your question.